# Steamworks SDK 1.52 introduces ShowFloatingGamepadTextInput... but where is it?

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

It's listed on the API page here: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUtils

And it's mentioned in the release notes here: https://store.steampowered.com/news/group/4145017/view/2984186817523157398

BUT it seems to be missing from the SDK dlls completely... so what am I missing? Release notes say it's only implemented on the SteamDeck, but there is no function for me to call...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Valve has confirmed that the flat symbol is missing and this will be fixed in SDK 1.53...